# Set default margins in cups?

Tags: rhel, configuration, cups

We just updated our server from CentOS 6 to RHEL 7 and after setting up our HP LaserJet 600 from ppd, I'm noticing that all print jobs now have about a 2" margin at the top of the page.

Is it possible to define margins in a configuration file?  [This reply](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/setting-default-printer-with-cups%3B-also-changing-top-and-bottom-margins-904853/#post4481464) suggests that margins can be set with some arguments to lpr, but I'd rather store them in a conf file.

```
using lp: 

-o page-bottom=N

-o page-left=N

-o page-right=N

-o page-top=N

Sets the page margins when printing text files. 
The values are in points - there are 72 points to the inch.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `loptions` command?

Comment: I haven't, though I see it is spelled `lpoptions`

Comment: Oop, sorry, yeah, typo.  `lpoptions` allows you to set per-user or global defaults for each printer.

Comment: Are the changes persistent?

Comment: Yup!  They update config files `/etc/cups/lpoptions` or `~/.cups/lpoptions`

Comment: So I just issued `lpoptions -p someprinter -o page-top=72`, then `lpoptions -p someprinter -l | grep page` - and get nothing.   The page margin wasn't affected when i printed a job with `lpr -P someprinter /some/file.doc`

Comment: I do see the `page-top` option in `/etc/cups/lpoptions` however.

Comment: It turns out this worked - if you'll add this as an answer I'll credit you appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard options can be set with the `lpoptions` command.

If run as a normal user the file `$HOME/.cups/lpoptions` is set.

If run as the `root` user then the system defaults `/etc/cups/lpoptions` is set.

This can be used to change various settings (eg double sided printing) and `page-top`.